# getting total duration based on continuous occurrence of a condition in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, rstudio

I have a dataframe like this. I want to find the duration for whcih either v1 or v2 is above 110.

```
timestamp              v1     v2
    14-05-2019 04:28    112.2   111.0
    14-05-2019 04:30    112.2   110.9
    14-05-2019 04:39    101.4   101.8
    14-05-2019 04:40    108.0   108.8
    14-05-2019 04:45    101.1   101.5
    14-05-2019 04:46    100.8   101.2
    14-05-2019 05:32    111.6   111.5
    14-05-2019 05:36    111.5   111.5
    14-05-2019 05:39    111.5   111.5
    14-05-2019 05:41    111.5   111.5
    14-05-2019 05:46    111.5   111.4
    14-05-2019 05:46    111.5   111.3
    14-05-2019 05:47    111.5   111.3
    14-05-2019 05:51    111.2   111.2
    14-05-2019 05:56    111.2   111.2
    14-05-2019 05:57    111.2   111.2
```

Mycode :

```
str = 0
end = 0
dur = 0
diff = 0
for (i in (1:norws(x))) {
  if((x['v1'][i,] >=110) || (x['v2'][i,] >=110)){
    if((str !=0) && (i-str == 1)){
      str = i}else{
        str = i
        end = i - 1
      }}
  if((str<end) && (end != 0)){
    diff =  as.numeric(x[end,1] - x[str,1],units="mins")
    dur = dur + diff
  }}
print(dur)
```

I want to get the duration of continous data where either v1 or v2 is greater than 110. Also if 
both start and end are same,them that is not considered or the difference is 0 sec.
  I will get two sets here :

```
14-05-2019 04:28    112.2   111.0
14-05-2019 04:30    112.2   110.9
```

here the time is 2 minute 14-05-2019 04:30 - 14-05-2019 04:28
Similarly,

```
14-05-2019 05:32    111.6   111.5
14-05-2019 05:36    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019 05:39    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019 05:41    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019 05:46    111.5   111.4
14-05-2019 05:46    111.5   111.3
14-05-2019 05:47    111.5   111.3
14-05-2019 05:51    111.2   111.2
14-05-2019 05:56    111.2   111.2
14-05-2019 05:57    111.2   111.2
```

here the time is 25 minute. ie, 14-05-2019 05:57 - 14-05-2019 05:32 
So, totally I get : 27 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach of your question.

It uses `data.table::rleid()` to create groups based on the condition `v1 or v2 > 110`. It then summarises on thw rows where this condition is valid, by subtracting the first timestamp of each group from the last timestamp of each group. This results in a column `duration` of difftimes by group.

Alternatively, you can calculate the entire sum of all duration. `format()` is used to output the answer as a string, in stead of a difftime.

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("timestamp              v1     v2
14-05-2019T04:28    112.2   111.0
14-05-2019T04:30    112.2   110.9
14-05-2019T04:39    101.4   101.8
14-05-2019T04:40    108.0   108.8
14-05-2019T04:45    101.1   101.5
14-05-2019T04:46    100.8   101.2
14-05-2019T05:32    111.6   111.5
14-05-2019T05:36    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019T05:39    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019T05:41    111.5   111.5
14-05-2019T05:46    111.5   111.4
14-05-2019T05:46    111.5   111.3
14-05-2019T05:47    111.5   111.3
14-05-2019T05:51    111.2   111.2
14-05-2019T05:56    111.2   111.2
14-05-2019T05:57    111.2   111.2")

#create timestamps
DT[, timestamp := as.POSIXct( timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%YT%H:%M" )]
```

**code**

```
#create groups based on v1|v2 > 110
DT[, group_id := rleid( v1 > 110 | v2 > 110 ) ][]
#group by group_id, only on rows where v1 or v2 > 110
DT[ v1 > 110 | v2 > 110, ][, .(duration = max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) ), by = .(group_id)]
```

**output**

```
#    group_id duration
# 1:        1   2 mins
# 2:        3  25 mins
```

**alternative summary**

replace last line of code with:

```
format( 
  sum( 
    DT[ v1 > 110 | v2 > 110, ][, .(duration = max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) ), by = .(group_id)]$duration 
  )
)
```

which gives the total of all 'groups'.

```
#27 mins
```

## update based on question in comment

To include start and end of each period, use:

```
DT[ v1 > 110 | v2 > 110, ][, .(start = min(timestamp),
                               end = max(timestamp),
                               duration = max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) ), 
                           by = .(group_id)][,group_id := NULL]

#                  start                 end duration
# 1: 2019-05-14 04:28:00 2019-05-14 04:30:00   2 mins
# 2: 2019-05-14 05:32:00 2019-05-14 05:57:00  25 mins
```

Comment: Also, How to get the cumulative sum of minutes and to display each start date and end date instead of groupid?

Comment: convert the timestamp to numeric before subtraction, or read `?difftime`

Comment: DT[, group_id := rleid( v1 > 110 | v2 > 110 ) ][] not showing all conditions. if I choose >95 i should get many, but I am only getting 3 items